# Zend Framework-where do calls to my methods go? Controller of Model?

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, model, controller

I'm confused about exactly what I should have in my controller and what in my method.

Specifically, I have this in the action method:

```
  public function upcomingshowsAction()
    {
       $gcal = $this->_validateCalendarConnection();
       $uncleanedFeedArray = $this->_getCalendarFeed($gcal);
       $finishedFeedArray = $this->_cleanFeed($uncleanedFeedArray); 
    $this->view->googleArray = $finishedFeedArray;

    }
```

And then (incorrectly I know), I have my methods still in the bottom of my controller.

So what I'm wondering, is for those methods in the upcomingshowsAction method, should all the actual methods just be in one model and then I'd have something like this:

```
  public function upcomingshowsAction()
    {
       $finishedFeedArray = new Application_Model_calendarModelPage();
    $this->view->googleArray = $finishedFeedArray;

    }
```

And then something like this in the model:

```
class Application_Model_CalendarModelPage
{

       $gcal = $this->_validateCalendarConnection();
       $uncleanedFeedArray = $this->_getCalendarFeed($gcal);
       $finishedFeedArray = $this->_cleanFeed($uncleanedFeedArray); 


    public functions
   {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

Am I on the right track here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second way is the way to go. The controller is here only (mostly) to get some data from the model and pass it to the view. All your business logic should go into the model.